# Unable to print Json result String for Google CSE

Tags: php, json

I am new to Json, I've applied the way that worked for google image API and i wondering is it the same way to use it to Google CSE?

```
$url ="https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=WHATEVER&cx=017728263617760474213:e_b2kmmuyco&q=standard%20form";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://localhost/GSearch2.php");
$body = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($body);
print_r($json->items);
```

There is no results nor errors appearing

Comment: Post the output of `echo ini_get('display_errors');` and `var_dump($json);`

Comment: ini_get('display_errors') = 1 and var_dump($json) is NULL
May i know whats wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

[From the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

> NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.

Since recursion depth was increased from 128 to 512 in PHP 5.3.0, there's a good chance that's not the issue, so `$body` probably does not contain valid JSON. Ensure that the value of `$url` points to valid JSON and look into [`json_last_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)

Comment: $URL has no problem and Json_last_error() has zero error. Could it be the problem is from Curl part?

Comment: `var_dump($body)`? `echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);`?

Comment: var_dump($body) returned bool(false) and echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); returned 0

Comment: OK HTTP 0 means cURL got no data back and when I visit that URL I notice I get (in JSON no less) an error amounting to HTTP 400 BAD REQUEST. That tells me you're probably not supposed to be hitting this URL directly but doing something like POST-ing data to it, which you can easily do with cURL. Does this sound like something you've read in the documentation? I apologize, but I've never worked with the Google Image API.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try checking the HTTTP response body [may be by printing it]?

Some times a Webservice like Google indicate server side errors in the json content itself.

Ex:

You are expecting a json string `{ "items": "Sample item" }`

but the response json string was something like `{ "error" : "invalid key/id1" }`

*[Sorry, I am not very good at PHP, but I have worked with Google APIs and CURL]*

Comment: There is no error displaying at all nor results, so from what you see, the codes above seems legit?

Comment: I've tried insert the $url value into browser and successfully printed json result. However I dunno how to make it dynamically and decode them. By using the code above, I able to decode google image which is also Json however its not working for Google CSE?